# pyspark streaming TaskCompletionListenerException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

**pyspark streaming read kafka TaskCompletionListenerException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1**

```
19/12/12 12:49:01 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 893.0 (TID 14716, slave03, executor 6): org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Spark UI for that failed task?

Comment: before `df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rowrdd)`   after  `df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rowrdd, **schema**)`   solved the problem,maybe if dont't have schema, pyspark streaming take first 100 lines judge the schema,Consume a lot of resources